# what approach to take for testing asyncConnect

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using Jest + Enzyme for testing my Reacts components, but asyncConnect code runs in server side, so I dont know whats is the best manner to test this part of code.

```
export default asyncConnect(
[
 {
  promise: ({ store: { dispatch, getState }, location, helpers }) => {
    //dipatch some actions
    //I want to test this code
  }
 }
],
 mapStateToProps,
 mapDispatchToProps
)(Home);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that instead of using an arrow function, define the function separately just like mapStateToProps so you can test it individually. Then you can mock it here to simplify testing this container.

Comment: I'll do that. Reading the library docs I realize that the asyncConnect dispath a "@redux-conn/BEGIN_GLOBAL_LOAD" action, so I can test if that action is dispatched and test my function individually.